# Vlookup -1 What formula could do this in Google Sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, array-formulas, gs-vlookup

I understand Vlookup cant look at -1 from the value it normally searches for.

Is there a function that does?

I looked at Offset but my criteria is a combination of letters & Numbers  e.g. G01A1 - Offset only does numbers.

It needs to reference another google sheet inside the same workbook.

So G01A1 is in Column A Sheet 1 and in Column B Sheet 2 (hence why I want it to look 1 left in sheet 2). The answer would be A11180

see link. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/144a1WwdlmSHUdsWk1IR8YiFb_7pCx7kbCPZPbLUDmew/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

yes. use `VLOOKUP`:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(A2:A, {Sheet2!B2:C, Sheet2!A2:A}, {3, 2}, 0)))
```

[image: 0]